# What is the underlying logic for generating an icon map for a custom registered layout?

Tags: 8, layout-builder

There seems to be a dearth of information on the internet about how to generate an `icon_map` for newly registered layouts in Layout Builder.

I've gotten as far as [finding a patch file](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2660124-layout-116.patch) from [the project](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2660124) that includes a poorly-documented comment that unfortunately doesn't shed much light on this:

```php
/**
 * Builds a render array representation of an SVG based on an icon map.
 *
 * @param string[][] $icon_map
 *   A two-dimensional array representing the visual output of the layout.
 *   For the following shape:
 *   |------------------------------|
 *   |                              |
 *   |             100%             |
 *   |                              |
 *   |-------|--------------|-------|
 *   |       |              |       |
 *   |       |      50%     |  25%  |
 *   |       |              |       |
 *   |  25%  |--------------|-------|
 *   |       |                      |
 *   |       |         75%          |
 *   |       |                      |
 *   |------------------------------|
 *   The corresponding array would be:
 *   - ['top']
 *   - ['first', 'second', 'second', 'third']
 *   - ['first', 'bottom', 'bottom', 'bottom'].

...
```

It doesn't say *why* we'd use keywords like `first`, `third`, and `bottom` — or even what each term actually means to the Layout Builder module. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason as to how this is supposed to work. The documentation is also [severely lacking](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/layout-api/how-to-register-layouts#using-class-key).

What is the underlying logic behind the generation of icon maps, and how does it actually work?

Comment: For example, why isn't the first line `['top', 'top', 'top', 'top']` instead of just `['top']`? If LB automatically knows to handle that case, it should be documented somewhere.

Comment: Taking a guess...if you look in layout_builder/layout_builder.layouts.yml it defines a couple of icon maps, and immediately afterwards defines regions, with matching labels. So the keys are possibly region machine names. They may of course be arbitrary, and just used to tie the cells of the layout together when they span multiple rows/columns. Still guessing, I'd say that each inner array is treated as a row of the layout, and each element in those array defines elements of _n_ width, where _n_ is determined by the other items in the array. If that make sense

Comment: I suggest you ask about this on #layouts Drupal slack channel and report back ;) I noticed some changes in the LB version that was included in Drupal core, but the documentation still seems to rely on the previous versions. Older versions used the "3-layer cake" icons you see in screenshots, but if you check the current version the icons/layouts only designate how many _columns_ there are in a row. So each section is meant to support columns-in-one-row layouts, not complex CSS-grid-like layouts. I guess they never did, it's just the interface that changed to be more clear.

Comment: I think @Clive is right. Since the longer array has 4 items, each column gets the 25% of the space. To  give the 50% space to *second*, *second* must be repeated twice. As for using `['top']` instead of `['top', 'top', 'top', 'top']`, I guess that is a special case that is handled by the code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It's the other way around - every item is considered 100% width by default, until/unless the rest of the row dictates otherwise

Comment: @Clive In both the cases, the code is able to handle the `['top']` case.